# Setting Filename modification Replace option in WinSCP .NET TransferSettings

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

In the WinSCP application there is a check box in the Transfer settings dialog to indicate if certain filename characters should be replaced when a file is transferred.

It's the *Replace* check box in the *Filename modification* group.

[image: WinSCP Transfer settings dialog]

Where is this option in C# WinSCP.net?
I've looked on the [`WinSCP.TransferOptions` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions), but I can't see this option.

Can someone please tell me how I set the *File Modification Replace* option in WinSCP .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ReplaceInvalidChars` raw transfer setting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#replaceinvalidchars):

```
var options = new TransferOptions();
options.AddRawSettings("ReplaceInvalidChars", "0");
```

And then use the [`TransferOptions` instance](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions) when calling file transfer method (such as [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles)).

WinSCP GUI can even [generate the code for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code).

Comment: You are correct. Just tried it. Thank you.